# How to find the direction in which a function does not change at a point?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have a function $f(x, y)$ and a point $P = (x_{0}, y_{0})$. I need to find the direction $\vec{u} = (a, b)$, among four options, in which the functon $f$ does not change. How can I do that?

**UPDATE:** So I just calculate $D_{\vec{u}} f(x_{0}, y_{0}) = f_{x} (x_{0}, y_{0}) \cdot a + f_{y} (x_{0}, y_{0}) \cdot b$ and look in which of the given directions it is zero, right?

Comment: The directional derivative will tell you the rate of change of $f$ in the direction of a given $(a,b)$.

Comment: You can find the gradient of f at P, and then see which directions are orthogonal to the gradient.

Comment: @JoeJohnson126 So I just calculate $D_{\vec{u}} f(x_{0}, y_{0}) = f_{x} (x_{0}, y_{0}) \cdot a + f_{y} (x_{0}, y_{0}) \cdot b$ and look where this is zero, right?

Comment: @ArthurCampbell Yes.

Answer (score 3):

Compute the vector $$\mathbf v = \begin{bmatrix} 
-\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} (x, y) \\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} (x, y)
\end{bmatrix}. 
$$
The instantaneous rate of change of $f$ in the direction $\mathbf v$ (at $(x, y)$) will be zero.